# Product of subgroups of a group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Suppose $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ where $H$, $K$ are subgroups of $G$.

I know if $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$ and their intersection is trivial then $hk=kh$ for every $h\in H$ and $k\in K$.

So my question is:

> Is there any other condition, where we could say their elements commute? Or is this the only condition where $hk=kh$ for every $h\in H$ and $k\in K$.

Comment: See also "[centralizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear the condition is not the “only one”; for example, if $G$ is abelian (or at least one of them is contained in the center) then you will have $hk=kh$ for all $h\in H$ and $k\in K$.

Then again, in both those cases you have that at least one of $H$ and $K$ are normal in $G$. That’s not required in general.

Unfortunately, the answer is rather pedestrian, in that the condition is simply a fancy way of codifying “every element of $H$ commutes with every element of $K$”, so that the answer unpacks to saying “this happens if and only if it happens.”

Explicilty, given a group $G$ and a set $X$, the *centralizer of $X$* is defined to be
$$C_G(X) = \{g\in G\mid gx=xg\text{ for all }x\in X\}.$$
The centralizer does have some interesting properties. For example, $C_G(X) = C_G(\langle X\rangle)$, so you may restrict the arguments to subgroups. Also, the centralizer defines a [Galois connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection) from the lattice of subgroups to itself. In particular, the “double centralizer” construction (mapping a subgroup $H$ to $C_G(C_G(H))$) is a [closure operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator) on the subgroups of $G$.

Here, you have that:

> Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$. The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $hk=kh$ for all $h\in H$ and $k\in K$.
> 2. $H\subseteq C_G(K)$.
> 3. $K\subseteq C_G(H)$.

But when you unpack that you will see that it “really” just says “it happens if it happens”.

Of course there are conditions that will imply it, such as the one you note. I will also point out that if this holds, then trivially $H$ and $K$ are both normal in $\langle H,K\rangle = HK$.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I agree with your last point of normality of $H$, $K$ in $HK$. Can we say anything about normality of $H$ and $K$ in $G$?

Comment: @Kavita: No; they need not be normal in $G$, even if they centralizer each other.